# Accessing common shared variable between two coroutines

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working on Python3.6 with GCP PubSub.

1. I am getting a callback from PubSub for the subscribed topic.
2. After receiving the callback message, I Queued the message and ACK
3. I processed the received message in init_apns_process()

**Future Problem:**

If I ACK the callback instantly(which am doing) and while `processing(init_apns_process)` an exception occurred then I will lose my message from either end.

**Expectation:**

Not to ACK PubSub before completion of `init_apns_process()`.

My solution so far:

```
apns_msg_queue = queue.Queue()
start_time = 0


async def init_apns_process(message):
    logging.info("Process Msg: {0}".format(message))
    await send_apns_notification(token)


async def send_apns_notification(device_token):
    global start_time
    apns = None
    apns = mi_apns_dev
    apns_payload = {"alert": "hello world 121", "serial": 21, "sound": "mov.mp3",
                    "mutable-content": "1", "category": "done", "id": -9999}

    if apns is not None:
        request = NotificationRequest(
            device_token=device_token,
            message={"aps": apns_payload}
        )

        ret = await apns.send_notification(request)
        if not ret.is_successful:
            logger.error(
                f"Failed to send APNS notification ID:")
        else:
            logging.info(f"Successfully sent APNS notification"
                         f" Time Taken in processing: {time.time() - start_time}")
             #update shared FLAG

def callback_value(message):
    apns_msg_queue.put(message)
    # return based on value of shared FLAG
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.setup()
    mi_apns_dev = APNs('apns.pem', use_sandbox=False)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    subscriber = sub.PubSubSubscriber()
    subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name, callback_value, auto_ack_on_received=False)

    while True:
        if apns_msg_queue.qsize() > 0:
            msg = apns_msg_queue.get()
            if msg is None:
                break
            loop.run_until_complete(init_apns_process(msg))
        time.sleep(5)
```

Can have some shared flag between above two tasks and ACK PubSub based on its value?

Comment: You don't have threads. You are using asyncio *coroutines*.

Comment: Now, it may well be that Google's pubsub uses threads in their library but that's not evident in your question if that's the case, nor is this an area I can help with.

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters. But what do you mean by 'coroutines' specific? Are those not running on different threads here?
In Debugger, I can see both on diff. threads.

Comment: Nothing in your code here spawns threads. However, it is possible that `sub.PubSubSubscriber()` creates a thread and calls `callback_value()` from that thread. If so, be sure to use [the provided tools to start further callbacks and tasks in the right thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading).

Comment: You perhaps want to [read up on coroutines](https://cheat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/asyncio.html) to understand the difference between threads and coroutines.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right. GCP pubsub creates a thread and `callback_value()` from that thread.